# Light Behind Texture (Transmission)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, light, eevee-render-engine

I have a model that uses a transmission texture. What the texture is suppose to do is when the lighting is behind the it, it will give the other side a somewhat glow effect as if the light traveled through it.

I'm sure it's subsurface, but I'm unsure. I also read a similar case to a recent question I asked, but the results didn't come out correct. Does this only work in Cycles, or can the nodes by accessed in Eevee engine?

Yes, the model is a Nintendo model, and one texture is suppose to have a glow effect when light passes through.

Comment: Subsurface Scattering may be what you're looking for, you also have Translucent BSDF, it will be much lighter to calculate but it won't take the thickness of the object into account, so you should try these two

Comment: Subsurface and translucent ([just tested here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVvC8.png)) work without any extra steps? What have you  actually tried prior to asking this question? ( *Does this only work in Cycles, or can the nodes by accessed in Eevee engine?* takes about 2 minutes to figure out.) Perhaps you need to refine your question with what your actual problem is about.

Comment: to add to Leander, did you try the Transmission factor in the Principled BSDF and if so what's not working for you? Which "recent question" are you referring to?

Comment: I was referring to this question. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/157664/shine-through-texture?noredirect=1#comment267256_157664